# JS to use in Navigation - Toggle

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, jquery

I have a menu very similar to Prada's (www.prada.com). When the user clicks on the word 'MENU' I want the image to change from the lines to a cross. The cross stays until the menu is closed again. Any idea how to do this? I'm not sure if the lines are an image or...?

Here is my current code. I have the sliding feature working, I just need to work out the image / lines next to the word 'MENU'.

```
<div class="skip-links">

<a class="skip-link skip-nav" href="#header-nav">

<span class="icon"></span>
<span class="label">

MENU

</span>
```

jquery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('.skip-links').hide().before('<a href="#" id="toggle-skip-links"     class="button">Open/Close</a>');
jQuery('a#toggle-skip-links').click(function() {
jQuery('.skip-links').slideToggle(200);
return false;
});
});
```

UPDATE:

I am using the following codepen:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PqGryp

Only it doesn't seem to be working on my end. The javascript isn't being triggered. Any ideas? I have placed the javascript into 'app.js'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some simple examples over at [codepen](http://codepen.io/tag/hamburger/) mate

- http://codepen.io/elijahmanor/pen/Igpoe
- http://codepen.io/kretzm/pen/guwEf

Hopefully helps achieve what you are wanting

Comment: Thanks! I actually had found these in the meantime, but these are better! hanks for your help!

Comment: Please see updated question. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have a link to your page? You may need to use the exact HTML from the codepen as well as the CSS as there maybe a conflict in the your code.

Comment: I'm working remotely so don't have the 'live' link. Am using the exact HTML and CSS, it seems to be that it's not picking up the JS though. Last time I had problems with .js someone had me add in the 'JQuery' bits, could that be the problem?

Comment: I think maybe that dont add the javascript code to the jQuery run script but add it separately in its own script tag <script></script> as its not jQuery dependent function..

Comment: How do I do that, sorry? Not too familiar with javascript / jQuery

Comment: Add to your head.phtml file would be easiest. Just add <script>document.querySelector( ".skip-link" )
  .addEventListener( "click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle( "active" );
  });</script>  should do the trick..

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working. Added to 'head.phtml', also tried adding to 'header.phtml' since this is where the call is for skip-link, but it doesn't work in either.

Comment: Forked the codepen (http://codepen.io/Bennith/full/YXGoBq/) item and added jQuery and is working. What jQuery version are you using? Is the script showing up when you view "page source"? Maybe prototype or scriptaculous are causing an issue

Comment: I believe i'm running 1.10.2.min.js

Comment: I ended up just using a different Codepen (http://codepen.io/designcouch/pen/Atyop) and it worked. Thanks for all your help!